# Manage each levels permissions of all site collections on one webapplication

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, web-application

I have a webapplication with somes sites collections.

I want to create a custom level permission "AdminCol"(Site administration without permission to create a sub-site) and apply this level to be present on each site collection of my webapplication.

My goal is to govern is to give "AdminCol" level permission for each site collection if I want or not. And administrate the level permissions of all "AdminCol" users.

What I tested :
- manage on the web application : the permission policy offer a level permission for the entire webapplication. Not disponible on each site collection to activate if wanted
- the level permissions come from site collection and are different from each site template. But creating a template don't conserve level permission

Somebody have an idea? or how can we govern administration privilèges on an web application?

thx for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution : have site collection access, define a new level permission, test it, do a powershell script to copy/past it on each site collection.